# How to use interface method?

Tags: java, javafx

I have multiple classes extending different classes. Example:
class MyVBox extends VBox
class MyHBox extends HBox

VBox and HBox are extending Node.

I use a void `changeNode(Node node)` to change the contents of my JavaFX program.
In the function `changeNode` I want to use a method of the class `node` which all `My*****` classes should also extend, this isn't possible in Java so I tried it using interfaces (`class MyVBox extends VBox implements MyNode`)

```
public interface MyNode {
    public boolean canClose = true;
}
```

How do I bind `node` to MyNode to use it's variables in `changeNode()`?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: why would you even set a flag like that?

Comment: @Stultuske When I `changeNode` I want to see if the user has data in the other node that can be lost, so when I changed text in some node and didn't save it sets it to false, then I can check if I can change nodes with the `canClose` variable that all My**** should have. Thanks for helping

Comment: Fields declared in interfaces are always static, regardless of whether you use the `static` keyword.  If you want both classes to have a canClose state, each will have to declare their own canClose field.

Comment: @Banjer all variables declared in an interface are (by default) public static final. you can't change the value

Comment: @VGR Thanks for helping! How can I use the function `public boolean canClose() { return canClose; }` (that is in My***** class) in the `changeNode(Node node)` function? I somehow have to show that I can use a `canClose()` function on every Node.

Comment: `public boolean canClose();` is all the interface can do.  Each class will have to implement it.  It is not possible to write a full implementation that is inheritable.  You can, however, write a separate concrete class to do this work, and make use of composition instead of inheritance, which is considered a better design in most situations.

Comment: @VGR Solved! Thanks for helping!